# Issue with SQL Azure connection string in Excel

Tags: sql, database, excel, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to create a connection string which contains SQL login information for use in Excel

The connection string I have been using is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=vw-AdventureWorks;Extended Properties=""
```

Which works fine, but when adding user/password fields, like this

```
Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=vw-AdventureWorks;User ID=[Id]@[server];Password=[password];Extended Properties=""
```

It throws an error stating the initialization of the database has failed, but the database is verified to be up and the string connects perfectly fine without the user/password fields

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the following connection string. I still don't know why the original one could not connect.

```
Server=tcp:[server].database.windows.net,1433;Data Source=[databasename];Initial Catalog=[database name];User ID=[Username];Password=[Password];
```